# Hit an API with Uppercase letter in Android

Tags: android, case-sensitive, adyen

I am making a POST call to the URL from Postman and it works fine:

> .../v1.0/shoppingCart/...

But when i pass my url String to Adyen's SDK for hitting my server, it gets converted to:

> /v1.0/shopping\u0421art/

ad call fails due to exception:

> com.adyen.core.exceptions.UnexpectedException: {"status": "NOT_FOUND", "message": ".../v1.0/shopping\u0421art/..."}

I know that having URLs with both cases is not a recommended practice, but here do i have a way to get it work from Android or its necessary to change the Endpoint. As case-sensitivity is working with other Retrofit calls. But when passing to Adyen its throwing exception mentioned above.

Comment: Two problems here: `\u0421` is not the way unicode characters are represented in URIs and the character U+0421 is not a capital C.

Comment: so in which area you suggest me to work, i am sort of stuck here

Comment: I guess, you have to find out why it  is happening.

Comment: in my logs its appearing as is, but in logs of Adyen its gets converted. And in Adyen's AsyncHttpClient i see no encoding stuff at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+0421 is unicode for CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/421/index.htm

Could the C in shoppingCart be not a capital C, but CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES?

Comment: Yes, it was not C instead Cyrillic Capital Letter ES.